# Scala Could not find implicit value supplied by mixin

Tags: scala, implicit

Using Scala version 2.11.12.

I can't seem to make the implicit `config` supplied by the mixin `Foundation` trait visible to the `Path` class' constructor.

```scala
case class Config() {
  val content = "hello"
}

trait Foundation {
  implicit val config: Config = Config()
}

trait PathBase {
  def somePath: String = "/user/xxx"
}

class Path(implicit val config: Config) extends PathBase {
  def someOtherPath: String = "/user/yyy"
}

trait NavigatorBase {
  protected implicit val hdfs: PathBase
}

trait Navigator extends NavigatorBase with Foundation {
//  private implicit val config1: Config = config
  protected implicit val hdfs = new Path
}
```

The above code raises the following error:

> :39: error: could not find implicit value for parameter config: Config
> protected implicit val hdfs = new Path

However, if I define a new implicit val using the `config` supplied by `Foundation` before calling `Path`'s constructor (see the commented line in the code), the code works. If I write `trait Navigator extends Foundation` without mixing in `NavigatorBase`, the code also works.

Is there a way to make the implicit `config` visible to `Path`'s constructor without having to define a new implicit variable or remove the extension of `NavigatorBase`?

Comment: It compiles for me: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/yRtIa6cMS2GktJzTi1q0Bg - Are you sure the error is real? maybe is just **IntellIJ**. Have you checked using your build tool? - If it is real, then are you sure you have all you need to reproduce it in that example? Maybe specify the **Scala** version.

Comment: Amended the question to include Scala version, thanks for the reminder! I encountered the error when using sbt and reproduced it in the spark-shell.

Comment: I tried the 2.11.12 scala version in Scastie and was able to reproduce the error. Seems to be a version issue. Thanks a lot for sharing this!

Answer (score 1):

Solution: As pointed out by @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez in the comment, use the latest version of Scala.

Scala 2.11.12 raises the error: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/yZU850eUQvKSt6LJ0GIeVA

Scala 2.13.4 works fine: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/8FYzJdimSOanOLow25rN3g